# Understanding $\rm SU(3)$ Gauge Invariance Through a Perturbation Theory

Tags: group-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, perturbation-theory, gauge-invariance, strong-force

Here I am modifying the field theory approach, since I never taken a course on Quantum Field Theory. I am exploring Gauge Invariance in $\rm SU(3)$ by the following approach (which technically is incorrect but nevertheless I think it is useful):

Let $(1,0,0)^T = \text{Red}$, $(0,1,0)^T = \text{Blue}$, and $(0,0,1)^T = \text{Green}$. Then a wavefunction can be represented as $(\Psi_1, \Psi_2, \Psi_3)^T$. Let $\alpha$ be a vector that represents a small change. Consider the following transformation:

$(\Psi_1, \Psi_2, \Psi_3)^T \to(1 - i\alpha\cdot\frac{\lambda}{2})(\Psi_1, \Psi_2, \Psi_3)^T$

Here $\lambda$ is a 8 component vector; each component $i$ is the $i^{th}$ Gelmann matrix (i.e. a generator of SU(3)). Hence we see that this transformation is perturbative.

Now the Gauge freedom is given by:

$\partial_{\mu} \to \partial_{\mu} + i\frac{\lambda}{2}\cdot S_{\mu}$

Here $S_{\mu}$ is the strong potential; it has 8 components and each component has 4 "slots" (one for time and 3 for space)

Consider the transformation: $S_{\mu} \to S_{\mu} + \partial_{\mu}\alpha + \alpha \times S_{\mu}$ . Here the cross product is defined by the $\rm SU(3)$ structure constants $f_{ijk}$ by the following: $(A \times B)_i = \sum_{i,j}^{8}f_{i,j,k}A_j B_k$

My goal is to show that following:

$\big[\partial_{\mu} + i\frac{\lambda}{2}\cdot \{S_{\mu} + \partial_{\mu}\alpha + \alpha \times S_{\mu}\}\big](1 - i\alpha\cdot\frac{\lambda}{2})(\Psi_1, \Psi_2, \Psi_3)^T \approx (1 - i\alpha\cdot\frac{\lambda}{2})[\partial_{\mu} + i\frac{\lambda}{2}\cdot S_{\mu}] (\Psi_1, \Psi_2, \Psi_3)^T$

I tried this approach in $\rm SU(2)$ and it worked via the usual vector identities (because the cross product in $\rm SU(2)$ had the same form as the cross product learned in school) and by ignoring $\alpha^2$ terms. However, I am not sure how to show this here. (I think it should work for small perturbations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have can be rewritten as
\begin{eqnarray} 
&&
\left( \partial_\mu +i A_\mu + i \partial _\mu \alpha + [\alpha,A_\mu] \right)
\left(1-i \alpha \right) \psi \approx 
\left(1-i \alpha \right) \partial _\mu\psi-i\partial _\mu \alpha \psi+iA_\mu\psi+A_\mu\alpha\psi+i\partial_\mu\alpha \psi+[\alpha,A_\mu]\psi \\
&&
\left(1-i \alpha \right) \partial _\mu\psi+iA_\mu\psi+A_\mu\alpha\psi+[\alpha,A_\mu]\psi=\left(1-i \alpha \right) 
\partial _\mu\psi+iA_\mu\psi+\alpha A_\mu\psi=\left(1-i \alpha \right) 
\partial _\mu\psi+i\left(1-i \alpha \right)A_\mu\psi \\
&&=\left(1-i \alpha \right)\left(\partial _\mu+i A_\mu \right)\psi
\end{eqnarray}